# How can I delete a Whatsapp group of which, I am the administrator?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am the admin of a WhatsApp group. I found that there is another group with same members, so the group I made is of no use. Now, How can I delete it?

Comment: This is a useful question, so ofcourse it needed to be closed.

Comment: If it is off-topic, then perhaps moving the question to the correct SE community would be better than closing. I found it VERY useful.

Answer (score 6):

1. **Remove all participants** other than yourself, first by pressing and holding their name
2. Finally, as Admin, exit yourself from the group by pressing "**Exit Group**" option underneath
3. Now, the delete group option should become visible: press "**Delete Group**"

It's all been explained on [WhatsApp FAQ - Group for Android](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23776567).

Comment: Actually, the link doesn't say about deleting group *on server side*. But as how WhatsApp group works (other user will be pointed as a new administrator when current administrator leaves), the only way to delete the group is by making it empty, which is the idea of this answer.